# Where I can find Stack Overflow’s open source dataset

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump

Based on the info posted [here](http://www.codethinked.com/tekpubs-mastering-linq-challenge),
I realize that there is a

> Stack Overflow’s open source dataset

How can I get it?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Comment: Run the query here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Answer (score 15):

Stack Exchange Creative Commons is hosted by the Internet Archive since January 2014.

[Blog Post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/)

[Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)

It is updated every 3 months.

Answer (score 3):

For more fun, you can also access it through BigQuery:

- API available!
- No limits on response size.
- JOIN with other datasets.

I wrote about it here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-bigquery-public-datasets-now-include-stack-overflow-q-a-5a8a7e371b52

The dataset docs:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

I think Kaggle also provide this dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stackoverflow).