# Any plans to refresh the Stack Overflow dataset?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump

The latest dataset hosted by the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) was created back in 2014. A lot of things have changed in 3 years. Any plans to refresh this dataset?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is already updated, request is pointless

Comment: Sure,  but let's move the answer by Oded to the linked question here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97067/where-i-can-find-stack-overflow-s-open-source-dataset?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I wasn't able to find the dataset until Oded posted the answer below.  So at least this question is useful to me.

Comment: No need for new answer, the existing answer can be edited.

Comment: No, it's not really useful. If anything, it's a duplicate of that other question. (as the answer is there)

Comment: I'll delete this one as soon as the existing answer is edited.  Right now it is outdated and causes confusion. Such confusion prompted me to ask this question and I am glad that @Oded answered

Answer (score 6):

It is updated every 3 months.

The last update was about a month ago:

[image]

A quirk in the bitorrent implementation of The Internet Archive is that instead of starting a new tracker for the newly uploaded data, they update the files (and file list) with the same tracker and .torrent file.